# Active Learning Suggestion in QnA maker is not visible in Service Setting

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

Active Learning Suggestion in QnA maker is not visible in Service Setting.
I have made the option active 2 weeks back but now when i go to Service Setting, I don't see the option of Enable Active Learnig.
QnA DataService version : 5.46.0
Also, when I go to my Knowledge baseand click on View Options it shows "Hide Active Learning Suggestions" but in disabled mode.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

For QnA GA version, you need to turn it on. For QnA maker managed service, this is turning on by default.

This would be a QnA Maker managed service, which is in private preview. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/active-learning-suggestions?tabs=v1#turn-on-active-learning

For QnA Maker managed, active learning is turned on by default.

Thanks.